# Automatically run popup after 24 hours with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I have a angular modal popup with number of tabs. My requirement is when user clicks the "close" button on that popup where need to hide that popup for a 24 hours. Next time user comes to that page (after 24 hours) where it should be popped up again automatically. Can you tell me the best way to achieve this by using angularJS and local storage or  like that ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Popup opens when page loads :**

```
 $scope.Event.UI.MyModal.Open(); 
 $scope.Active = {
        Dashboard: true
     };
```

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Where did you get stuck? Does it matter if the user is able to circumvent this 24-hour delay (by for example, using a different browser / computer), or does the solution need to be secure?

Comment: @Chris Security is not a matter.This is just a hide a popup for a 24 H.At this moment this popup is showing every time user comes to this page.Which is some what annoying.That's why we need to hide this for 24 H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do that, most of them involving cookies (no need for local storage in my opinion):

1. Use native javascript get/set cookies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie
2. Use angular's $cookie service to read and write cookies: https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies (note that it does not let you set the expiration property, so you can put the timestamp inside the cookie and check if the time has passed)
3. Use some angular module for handling cookies more usefully, something like this: https://github.com/ivpusic/angular-cookie

Comment: Can you tell me how to trigger the popup again if time elapse (in side the angulajs controller) ?

Comment: @Sampath in much the same way you triggered it the first time... can you show your code so that I know how your are working with the popup?

Comment: I have updated the code.Please check that.I need to know whether should I use any event listener or something like that to listen the cookie's value change or like that ?

Comment: It depends on the usage of your app and how accurate your want that 24 hours to be. You can use $interval to check every 10 minutes for example